# routing of Zend framework

Tags: php, zend-framework, routes

I create a module in zend project and the module has it's own mvc folders, here's the structure of the module,

[image]
i want to open the index page which located in the view floder of the visit module

here's the path of the index.phtml

```
InspectionSys\application\modules\visits\views\scripts\visits\index.phtml
```

and I try to make routing to the index page in application.ini

```
resources.router.routes.user.route = /visit
resources.router.routes.user.defaults.module = visits
resources.router.routes.user.defaults.controller = visit
resources.router.routes.user.defaults.action = index
```

when I type http://localhost/zendApps/InspectionSys/visit it  returns 404 error page.

What should I do?

Comment: did you enable modules in your application.ini? It might help if you posted your application.ini

Answer (score 2):

Your controller's name is **`visits`** not `visit`.

Try replacing your route with this

```
resources.router.routes.user.route = "/visit"
resources.router.routes.user.defaults.module = visits
resources.router.routes.user.defaults.controller = visits
resources.router.routes.user.defaults.action = index
```

or define your route in bootsrap

```
 $routeUser = new Zend_Controller_Router_Route(
    '/visit',
    array(
        'module' => 'visits'
        'controller' => 'visits',
        'action' => 'index'
    )
);
$router -> addRoute('visit', $routeUser);
```

---

#### Update 1

The problem seems to be due to the root not being routed to `/public`.

1. **The proper way:** You need to setup a vhost and point the root to the `public` directory.
2. **Another Way:** You need to redirect every request inside `public` directory. The `.htaccess` for this file would be

   ```
   RewriteRule ^\.htaccess$ - [F]

   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} =""
   RewriteRule ^.*$ /public/index.php [NC,L]

   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/public/.*$
   RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /public/$1

   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
   RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]

   RewriteRule ^public/.*$ /public/index.php [NC,L]
   ```

Comment: I modify it, but the same problem!

Comment: Also it doesn't work :( Now I am using the public folder to reach all files!

Comment: That is the problem of .htaccess files. Where does your root point to?

Comment: @PalAla, Have you done as I have told you? Place two .htaccess file, one outside public and one inside. The one in my answer is placed outside the public folder