# Zendframework project shows xyz.com/public/ so how to remove public

Tags: php, zend-framework, .htaccess

My zendFramework application on server shows

```
xyz.com/public/login
```

i want it like

```
xyz.com/login
```

how to achieve this ? is it possible to do with `.htaccess` file?

Comment: Do you have .htaccess file already present on your public folder?

Answer (score 2):

This is my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9513265/295264) from another [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9513228/routing-of-zend-framework/9513265), but seems to fit in this question too. In the case you already have a `.htaccess` file inside `public`, use the `htaccess` solution from below.

The problem seems to be due to the root not being routed to `/public`.

1. **The proper way:** You need to setup a vhost and point the root to the `public` directory.
2. **Another Way:** You need to redirect every request inside `public` directory. The `.htaccess` for this file would be

   ```
   RewriteRule ^\.htaccess$ - [F]

   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} =""
   RewriteRule ^.*$ /public/index.php [NC,L]

   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/public/.*$
   RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /public/$1

   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
   RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]

   RewriteRule ^public/.*$ /public/index.php [NC,L]
   ```

Comment: Not working for me and are there securities issues if we'll use this?

Comment: @zuberSurya, I think You got me wrong. Place a `.htaccess` file outside the public folder, with above codes. And the `.htaccess` zf inside `public` folder previously should be kept as it is.

Answer (score 1):

You have to create a `virtual server` Zend have a [tutorial](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/learning.quickstart.create-project.html) to do so.

If you are not able to create virtual server by any reason. You can put the public `index.php` file outside the public folder. If you choose this method you have to add extra security methods, choosing this method lead to direct access of files.

You can prevent those direct access by creating `.htaccess` in those directories with these lines-

```
<Files *>
Deny from all
</Files>
```